# time.strptime doesn't parse timezone

Tags: python, strptime

```
time.strptime('Sun, 22 May 2022 10:50:14 +0000','%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
```

and

```
time.strptime('Sun, 22 May 2022 10:50:14 +0800','%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
```

both give the same result

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2022, tm_mon=5, tm_mday=22, tm_hour=10, tm_min=50, tm_sec=14, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=142, tm_isdst=-1)
```

and the their timestamps are the same.

Why `time.strptime` doesn't parse the timezone?

I am using python 3.10.4 on windows 11

Comment: For an answer, look at the docs for `strptime()`: Support for the `%Z` directive is based on the values contained in `tzname` and whether `daylight` is true. Because of this, it is platform-specific except for recognizing UTC and GMT which are always known (and are considered to be non-daylight savings timezones).

Only the directives specified in the documentation are supported. ... `strptime()` is independent of any platform and thus does not necessarily support all directives available that are not documented as supported.

Comment: @BoarGules Yes I have read the doc. It says that %Z is deprecated and I use %z instead. %z is used as "Time zone offset indicating a positive or negative time difference from UTC/GMT of the form +HHMM or -HHMM, where H represents decimal hour digits and M represents decimal minute digits [-23:59, +23:59]." according to the doc. But it doesn't parse the +0800 in my code.

Comment: The last time I looked (many years ago) Python's `strptime` simply called the one from the C compiler, so it depended on whether that C compiler handled it properly.  Many didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you use the method [datetime.strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)? When I tested locally, it seems to be able to take timezone into account even when comparing two time parse from different timezone

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> t1 = datetime.strptime('Sun, 22 May 2022 10:50:14 +0800','%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
>>> t2 = datetime.strptime('Sun, 22 May 2022 10:50:14 +0000','%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
>>> t1 == t2
False
>>> t1
datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 22, 10, 50, 14, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=28800)))
>>> t2
datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 22, 10, 50, 14, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
>>> t3 = datetime.strptime('Sun, 22 May 2022 10:50:14 +0000','%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
>>> t4 = datetime.strptime('Sun, 22 May 2022 18:50:14 +0800','%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
>>> t3
datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 22, 10, 50, 14, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
>>> t4
datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 22, 18, 50, 14, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=28800)))
>>> t3 == t4
True
```